# How to define the declared function - template struct member with unnamed template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template struct:

```
template<typename T2, class, typename, class T3 = vec1<T2> >
struct vec2
{
    template<typename D2, class, typename, class D3>
    void f14(int a);

    template<typename D2, class, typename, class D3>
    void f15(int a);
};
```

And I want to define, for example function f15. I have no idea, what should I write on the place of the "??". I tried to solve this problem in a different way. But compiler kills my dream to compile my program.

```
template<typename T2, class , typename , class T3>
template<typename D2, class , typename , class D3>
void vec2<T2,??,??,T3>::f15(int a) {  }
```

How should I define the function f15?

What is the scientific name for such constructions "class , typename ,"? 
I googled a lot ("unnamed template parameter", etc...), but I didn't found anything about it. I guess, it alikes the function with unnamed arguments. I would like to read something about it - from C++ standart or from other sources, but I don't know where the necessary information is.

Comment: The names don't have to match between the declaration and the implementation.

Comment: Why not just name your currently unamed type to pass them as template argument to vec2 ?

Comment: Why are they not named?

Comment: So, instead of "??" it is possible to generate any name?

Comment: `class` and `typename` here mean the same thing: the parameter is the name of a type.

Comment: Well see 0x499602D2's answer it's pretty simple. Template argument are like function argument, you just take them and pass them around.

Comment: I can add names to template arguments of struct declaration, and compiler will be happy. But I want to know, is it possible without naming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to name the parameter for the definition.

```
template <typename T2, class X, typename Y, class T3>
template <typename D2, class X2, typename Y2, class D3>
void vec2<T2, X, Y, T3>::f15<D2, X2, Y2, D3>(int a) {  }
```

Generally there is no real difference between using `typename` and `class` to define a type in the parameter list. The only difference is that when you are defining a template-template argument you must use `class`.

```
template <template <typename> class> struct A {};
//                            ^^^^^ class is required here
```

Moreover, when you are using a **dependent type** (a type derived from a template argument) you must use `typename` to define it. It is explained well in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: I'd add that the reason why you have to name them is: "When you omit the name, you're saying you don't need the parameter for anything. But in this case, you need it - to specify the particular definition. So you cannot omit the name."

Comment: Does the struct with named template arguments (which have the declarations only) have differences from the struct with unnamed struct arguments, but with defined function f15: template<typename D2, class, typename, class D3>  void f15(int a) {};

Comment: In other words, if I move the functions definition from such struct/class, etc... with naming of unnamed template arguments, do I break the program's logical structure?

Comment: Could you link the C++ standart part, where unnamed template parameters are described?

Comment: @LuckyMan No, you are not changing the logical structure. This is the same as leaving the argument names to a function prototype out, and then naming them when you define them. There is no difference too when it comes to templates. I don't have the standard with me right now, but I will try to look for the appropriate clause when I get one.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks a lot! Your tips were very useful! :)